# SQL - Select entries more than 1 day old. error #1305 Function doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, phpmyadmin

for a basic SQL command via PHPMyAdmin in MySQL I want to select items more than 1 day old. I'm getting a basic error saying that there's a SQL syntax error, but can't tell what I'm doing wrong here:

COMMAND:

```
select *
from table_name
where column_name < Date_Add(day, -1, GetDate())
and user_id = 1
and column_name <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

ERROR:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual for the right syntax to use near '-1, GetDate()) and user_id = 1 and column_name &lt;&gt; '0000-00-00 00:00:00' LIMI' at line 3
```

Any clues? Thx!!

Comment: yeah - that solved it. I will print the final version in another solution, below.

Comment: Cool happy you got it fixed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was thinking the syntax here is DATE_ADD.

Ok here is from the 5.0 reference guide:

> The DATE_ADD() function and its
>   synonym ADDDATE() allow you to add or
>   subtract an interval to the selected
>   date, date function or date constant.
>   DATE_SUB() and SUBDATE() work in the
>   same way but the interval specified is
>   subtracted. (If the interval was
>   negatvie DATE_SUB() makes it
>   positive).

```
mysql> SELECT NOW(), DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                            NOW(): 2008-09-25 11:43:29
DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH): 2008-10-25 11:43:29
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Try using NOW() for the error.

Comment: So, if I want dates more than 1 day ago, could I write:  DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)    ??

Comment: Take a look at http://www.electrictoolbox.com/date-add-mysql-intervals-dates/ and yeah I believe that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks NgM, that really helped.  DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) should be the same as  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) for anyone else experimenting with this...

Comment: Probably won't matter but here is good article for difference between Now() vs CurDate().  NgM used one, I used the other.  http://www.gizmola.com/blog/archives/51-Exploring-Mysql-CURDATE-and-NOW.-The-same-but-different..html

Answer (score 2):

Some engines (i.e. tsql) use DateAdd()...  MySql uses [Date_Add()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) - your missing an underscore.

Try

```
Date_Add(CurDate(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
```

Comment: Thanks - you're right - but Date_Add gives another error #1064. I've updated the question

Answer (score 1):

I voted up NgM's response ABOVE for his idea to use NOW() - here's the final version that worked:

```
select *
from table_name
where column_name < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
and user_id = 1
and column_name <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Isnt it

```
Date_Add(....)
```

or

```
AddDate(...)
```

Comment: It's Date_Add() but even with the new function name I still get a syntax error - any clues?

Comment: Which version of mysql you running?